# URL - PHP get variable and id

Tags: php, html, url

My Problem is that my link `localhost/index.php#add?id=2`  is not working.

So my Question is:

**How I can call an HTML id attribute and an PHP GET Variable in one url?**

**SOLVED**

```
?id=2#add
```

Comment: /index.php?id=2#add ?

Comment: `index.php?id=2#add`

Comment: Thanks `index.php?id=2#add` works

Answer (score 2):

You can use it as:

```
yoururl.com/index.php?id=2#add
```

In PHP you can get id from this QUERY STRING as like that:

```
<?
$id = $_GET["id"];
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to start a querystring with a `?` and seperate each parameter with a `&` like this

```
localhost/index.php?add&id=2
```

Then you can use the $_GET array in PHP like this

```
if ( isset( $_GET['add'], $_GET['id'] ) ) {
    // you are doing an ADD

    echo 'Doing an ADD with id=' . $_GET['id'];

}
```